# Cant extract "moving" data. Terminal show list = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Tags: python, selenium

In this page there is a table where in each row there is a plus “+” button, where if you click It more detailed info is displayed (the info I need).

Every Plus “+” button have the same class and also, only one piece of detailed info can be displayed at a time. So if I have clicked the first button, at the moment I click the second Plus “+” button, the detailed info of the first row disappears (closes).

The thing is, every time I click one button there is certain movement in the page and I suspect may be the cause of this but it made no sense. ¿Why I suspect this? Because the first item in the list its a text from other position within the row.

I managed to click each button one by one, but I can’t extract the data I want resulting in a list of just blank spaces like [other text from row '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

The code I’m using is this:

```
list = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='buttonclass']")
for x in range(len(elements)):
    elements[x].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td[class='class of info I want']")
    skutxt = results.text
    list.append(skutxt)

print(list)

Terminal shows: ['wrong text', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is `.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class = 'buttonclass']")` and `.find_element_by_css_selector("td[class='class of info I want']")` have the same length?

Comment: Hi ! Yes! They have the exact same length. This one .find_element_by_css_selector("td[class='class of info I want']") is "hidden" until I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Python [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function for parallel iteration.

Try following code:

```
text_list = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class='buttonclass']")
results = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td[class='class of info I want']")

for element, result in zip(elements, results):
    elements.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    text_list.append(result.text)

print(text_list)
```

But note `time.sleep(..)` is bad way, you can use other alternative.

Comment: Dear frianH, thank you so much again. Thank you for your time. Best regards!!